# How to prevent rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, react-hooks

I made this Component it sends props to checkbox and range components. When I was testing functionality of this 2 components I saw when I made a change in range component checkbox also rerender but it wasn't changed and the same when I change checkbox renage rerender.

**Problem**

- When I change range comp the second one also rerender

  ```
      const GeneratePassword = () => {
        // Checkbox
        const [state, setState] = useState({
          Symbols: false,
          capiatalLetters: false,
          digits: false,
        })

        const handleChange = (e) => {
          setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked })
        }

        // Range

        const [value, setValue] = useState(8)

        const handleInputChange = (event) => {
          setValue(event.target.value === '' ? '' : Number(event.target.value))
        }

        const handleBlur = () => {
          if (value < 8) {
            setValue(8)
          } else if (value > 30) {
            setValue(30)
          }
        }

        return (
          <Comp.StyledCheckboxContainer>
            <Comp.CheckboxBorder>
              <CheckboxContainer isCheck={handleChange} option={state} />
              <Range
                value={value}
                handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
                handleBlur={handleBlur}
                setValue={setValue}
              />
            </Comp.CheckboxBorder>
          </Comp.StyledCheckboxContainer>
        )
      }

      export default GeneratePassword
  ```

Comment: rerender is the only problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components are updated on each state change because their props change. Functions that are used as callbacks should be memoized to prevent this. That some of them rely on current state is a problem, they need to use updater function to avoid referring to stale state:

```
  const handleChange = useCallback((e) => {
    setState((state) => ({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked }))
  }, [])

  ...

  const handleInputChange = useCallback((event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value === '' ? '' : Number(event.target.value))
  }, [])

  ...

  const handleBlur = useCallback(() => {
   setValue(value => {
    if (value < 8) {
      return 8
    } else if (value > 30) {
      return 30
    }
   })
  }, [])
```

At this point child components are able to prevent unnecessary rerenders. If they don’t do this, they need to be additionally wrapped with `React.PureComponent` or `React.memo`. For arbitrary component a wrapper can be:

```
OptimizedComp = React.memo(props => <Comp {...props} />);
```

Comment: I get this warning : React Hook useCallback does nothing when called with only one argument. Did you forget to pass an array of dependencies?

Comment: and when i give empty array it`s rerender as before

Comment: Sure, empty array needs to be provided for all of them, fixed. Make sure that 3 of them were wrapped with useCallback

Comment: I made video showing this problem : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A4fiMOmzsbn4xJefwZwnntvjNPZdAij_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you provide a way to replicate your problem? Since Range is your own functional component and you can fix it, did you try the last recommendation from the answer, React.memo?

Answer (score 0):

It is because your callback for Checkbox component is defined inside parent which re-renders whenever range component changes causing a change is callback for Checkbox component since it gets new value on every render.

```
const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value === '' ? '' : Number(event.target.value))
}
```

On every render, `handleInputChange` gets a new value, a new reference. You need to use `React.useCallbak()` to keep the same value for all renders

```
const handleInputChange = React.useCallback((event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value === '' ? '' : Number(event.target.value))
}, []);
```